# What does return "" mean?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
   for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
     if ( alist.get(i).average() == d ) {
      return alist.get(i).getCountry();
     }
   }
   return "";
}
```

I need to return the name of the country which is in `alist.get(i).getCountry()`, but when I end the body with that it will say

error: missing {

When I put `return ""` it doesn't have an error.
What does `return ""` mean?

Comment: What you posted is just a fragment from a method.  The final `return` statement just returns an empty string, would happen if the earlier return does not occur.

Comment: You should return `null` instead of an empty string, to signal that the item wasn't found. You need a `return` statement at the end of the loop in case the item wasn't found inside the loop.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the average `d` is somewhere in the list? If not, what would you want to return in the case where it isn’t? Or if the list is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return "";` just returns an empty string.

If you put `alist.get(i).getCountry()` outside of the for loop it will not make sense. (I'm assuming that's what you mean by "end the body with that.") It depends on `i`, which only exists in the loop.

It's tough to see why you're getting that error without seeing more of your code.

Comment: No it isn't. The method returns a value from inside the loop, so it needs to return a value at the end of the loop as well.